Lists of literary works on topic or off topic?
I was looking for an online essential list of highly representative Italian literary works. For example the first 10, 50, 100, 500, etc.
I was surprised to find out that it is not so easy to find one - it is probably easier to make it. Would a question be on topic? If not, is there a way to rephrase the request so that it would be on topic?

Definitely on topic to me

Let's try then :-)

The problem is only the ranking: how do you rank works based on their significance? Wouldn't that be kind of a personal choice?

I think it is better to ask for an unsorted list of n works, perhaps with n variable: e.g. n = 10, 20, 30, 50, 100. However, as of now, the question has attracted comments, but not lists; I am afraid it was a flop :-)

Well, all your listed works and the other people have added in comments are already a good start for a list. Why don't you add those things as an answer, so that people can add further things in other answers? Then a moderator can merge them.

You mean I could make a new list in an answer? With only 10 works or considering more candidates?

With all the works listed in your question plus the additions in the comments. It won't be a satisfactory answer but it's a start! And you can always update it when new suggestions arrive either in comments or answers.
